# Google Location API - find business inside other business

Tags: api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-location-services

About a year ago, google maps added the "Located In" feature to places, so if a certain business in located inside another business its listing will show the relation.

This means that if a restaurant for example, is located inside a shopping mall, it will be stated that it is inside.

This means that google keep some kind of relation between places and "sub places" and I was looking for a way to query all places that are inside another place.

For example, If I want to go to a mall, and get all restaurants inside the mall.

I've read the google Places API, and it seems that the "near by" search is based mainly on point(long,lat) and radius, but I could not find a way to query by "located in" businesses.

If anyone is familiar with such a feature, I'd appreciate any help with that.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Places API doesn't support this functionality. I can see that similar issue was created in Google issue tracker 2 years ago:

[Bug: Places located inside another (mall, shopping centre) does not show up in results](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35830444)

However it looks like Google rejected it for some reason. I would suggest filing a new issue in Google issue tracker:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188872&template=789006

Hopefully Google replies something soon.

Comment: Thanks, thought I was missing something.